# Showing two different output in the same row side by side

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to show some output in a html table. The items has to be side by side. For example- I'm trying to create something like this-

```
            State :     in queue:
            state1      
            city1        2
            city2        0
            state2
            city4        0
```

But with my code I'm getting something like this:

```
      State :      in queue:

      state1
      city1
      city2
      state2
      city4     2
                  0
                  0
```

I've check every tag to find if I've made any mistakes as closing tag is important, but I can't seem to find my mistake. My code is given below:

```
      <table>


<p>
<tr>
<td><u>State :</u> </td>
        <td style="padding-left:50px">  <u> in queue:  </u></td>

    <?php

    foreach($states as $state):?>
    <tr>
            <td>


        <?echo $state->statename."<br/>";?>
        <?php  foreach($state->schools as $schools):;?>
                 <?php echo $Schools->schoolname."................"; ?></br>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>

            <td style="padding-left:50px">
                 <?php foreach ($area as $s): ?>
                 <?php  echo $s ;?></br>
                 <?php endforeach;?>

            </td>

        </tr>



   </td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: try <br clear="all" /> instead of <br>

Comment: your html code is seriously wrong, you're opening random tags and not closing them and seems like you don't know basics of building tables in html. i'd suggest trying to build this table without php code and have it display just like you want, so you can learn from such example how to build tables. sorry if this sounds discouraging but it is really a "elementary-school-case" ;)

Comment: Anywys better choice is to make 2 tables for each state..one for tags, another for values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in your css:

```
  #tbl_1 {
width: 150px;
float: left;

margin-left: 20px;
}


#tbl_2 {
width: 300px;
float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Then try to add these two different tables side by side
       
      State :

```
   foreach($states as $state):?>
    <tr>
            <td>


        <?echo $state->statename."<br/>";?>
        <?php  foreach($state->schools as $schools):;?>
                 <?php echo $schools->schoolsname; ?></br>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
     </table>
  //end of 1st table...//
```

//start of 2nd table...//

```
      <table id="tbl_2">....//similar as the previous </table>
```

hope this solve your problem..good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>ROW HEADING</th>
<th>ROW HEADING</th>
</tr>

<!-- foreach for state starts here -->
    <tr>
    <td>
    <!-- foreach for name goes here --> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- foreach for status goes here -->
    </td>
    </tr>
<!-- foreach for state ends here -->
</table>
```

Just be mindful of your table cell and row end tags and validate your output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first you have to delete the `<p>` after the `<table>`

secondly, you need a row (`<tr>`) for 'State :     in queue:'

smthing like

```
       <tr>
            <td>
                <u>State :</u> 
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:50px">  
                <u> in queue:  </u>
            </td>
        <tr/>
```

also, you need a row for each state, so you need

```
<?php foreach($states as $state):?>
            <tr><td><?echo $state->statename."<br/>";?></td><td></td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing td after tr that cant work :). check http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp for more info.

Comment: W3Schools is not a terribly high quality reference to point to. You've also not quite noticed the whole problem; there was *also* a closing td tag before the tr.